# Segmentation fault on memcpy() function

Tags: c, linux, memcpy

I have the following memory base address which contains some data of 256 bytes:

```
#define TX_PTR 0x40000008
```

Now I have the following array which will store the data from TX_PTR.

```
unsigned int tx_arr[64];
int i = 0;
for (i=0; i<64;i++)
{
   tx_arr[i]=0;
}
```

When I try to memcpy the data from the memory base address to the array by:

```
memcpy(&tx_arr, TX_PTR, 2*32*sizeof(int));
```

I get a segmentation fault.
I am running this code in linux. What could be the problem here?

Comment: what is TX_PTR?

Comment: It is a memory address defined as #define TX_PTR 0x40000008

Comment: It is an integer which is casted to void pointer and I am 100% sure that it not point to the valid memory location

Comment: The data is being written on that address by another c application. Its too complex and i cant mention that here. I have written the data myself and I can also read it correctly. But if I try to use memset, that isnt working.

Comment: How do you write from another application to that address? Because processes have separate memory spaces and to be able to share a specific address would require quite a bit of juggling. But `tx_arr` is a pointer and you take a pointer to the pointer, that doesn’t look good.

Comment: I am running freertos and openamp on a zynq board. I can run multiple applications on by the use of the openamp framework.

Comment: Can you all please assume that data is definitely present in that location, I can access it by directly reading it from the address but I cant read it with memcpy.

Comment: @KulaDamian Wile I don't think it matters that much in this particular case, at least try by calling memcpy the proper way: `memcpy(tx_arr, (void*)TX_PTR, sizeof tx_arr);`  (or if you like this alternative better: `memcpy(&tx_arr[0], TX_PTR, (void*)TX_PTR, sizeof(tx_arr));`

Comment: I found my problem. The address was mmapped to a virtual memory. I needed to put the virtual memory address in the memcpy function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am running freertos and openamp on a zynq board.

From this comment, I am led to believe that the "*memory*" is implemented in the FPGA's address space, or that FreeRTOS is running and has written to this memory.

If this is the case, then to access data that is physically located at a point in memory, you need to use `mmap()`.

Linux processes do not sit on phyisical addresses - the MMU will map virtual memory to physical memory.

To get access to physical memory, you need to use `mmap()` - something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define TX_ADDR 0x40000008
#define TX_LEN  256

void *my_memory;
int memfd;

memfd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
if (memfd == -1) {
    perror("open()");
    exit(1);
}

my_memory = mmap(NULL, TX_LEN, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, TX_ADDR);
if (my_memory == NULL) {
    perror("mmap()");
    exit(1);
}

/* use my_memory to access the data */
unsigned int tx_arr[64];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
   tx_arr[i] = 0;
}

memcpy(tx_arr, my_memory, sizeof(tx_arr));
```

After the call to `mmap()`, the memory will be available in your process' *virtual address space* at the address held in `my_memory` - don't use `TX_PTR`.

Note also, that `tx_arr` is an array, and thus can be passed as a pointer without using `&tx_arr`.